# Cosine Argument Simplification

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I've come across a puzzling example.

I have a $\cos(5t-10t)$ in a problem I am attempting to solve.

I would imagine this equals $\cos(-5t)$, but WolframAlpha tells me the result is, in fact, $\cos(5t)$; a positive argument...

Does anyone know why this works out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that one has
$$
\cos(-x)=\cos(x),\qquad x\in \mathbb{R},
$$ giving, with $x=5t$,
$$
\cos(-5t)=\cos(5t),\qquad t\in \mathbb{R}.
$$

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

cosine is an even function, hence $\cos(-x) = \cos(x)$.

Both your solution and Wolfram Alpha are correct.

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$Y=\cos(-5t)$ lies in the $4$th quadrant as - ve denotes that the 
Angle is being rotated. Clockwise from +ve x axis and cos 
Give positive results in the fourth quadrant so $\cos(5t)$  is same as $\cos(-5t)$.